# SQL: Delete every ID that's greater than or equal to

Tags: sql

I'm trying to make it so that I can run a SQL script that makes it so it deletes every account that has an ID greater than or equal to 3000.

This is what I have so far:

```
DELETE column WHERE `id` => 3000
```

Comment: Do you really store your accounts in a table named `column`?

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
DELETE column WHERE `id` => 3000
```

Via

```
DELETE from TableName WHERE id >= 3000
```

Column name no need to be covered by '' in sql. and where condition should be >= not =>

Comment: Hope this may help You!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you want to remove employees whose officeNumber is 4, you use the DELETE statement with the WHERE clause as the following query:

```
DELETE FROM employees
WHERE officeCode = 4
```

Comment: [link] http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-statement.aspx refer this for more details.